# Does ColdFusion Builder have a format document feature?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

Format document as in organize indentation of tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not, but it's been said that ColdFusion Builder 2 (Storm) will have one:

http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2010/10/27/ColdFusion-Builder-2-Storm--Sneak-Peak

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the newer versions of CFB (2.0 onwards) have this feature, which can be found on right click menu or by CTRL+SHIFT+F in windows. In Mac I guess the shortcut is Cmd+Shift+F.